# Should a logo always be square?

Tags: icons, design, typography

I want to create a new logo for myself.
Because I love typographic logos, I'll create such a logo.

The most of the logos I see are square, but for a typographic logo it is sometimes hard to create a square logo (the logo should stand for "stage picture").

So is it good practice to create a non-square logo or why should I defently use a square logo?

Comment: This is not really about UX topic but more graphic design.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about graphic design and not UX. Probably belongs over on [graphicdesign.stackexchange.com](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Abektes: Okay then sorry. But I I want more to know why it should be square (I don't think the most logos are square because of the designer who like this more, but because of the user experience), and not HOW should I design it...

Comment: And when I take a look to the "Related" Questions, there are a lot of questions about the size of some design elements. And exactly this is what I want to know.

Comment: @user1720004  1-1 symmetrical shapes are the first rule of universal aesthetics. It can be circle too. However it is the most primitive and grounded rule of aesthetics..If you break symmetry than you have a more sophisticated rule behind it. Jonathan Ive calls it grid and in fact nobody knows what it is...

Comment: “The most of the logos I see are square” You must live in a Lego world.

Comment: @Abektes — There is much more symmetry in a disc than in a square. Infinitely more.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco Yes indeed, circle is actually better than square because of the same reason that you mentioned.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you're mixing up *logo* and *icon*.

A logo doesn't have to be a square. There are several examples of famous non-square logos.
But an icon should be square. It is mostly used as gravatars or also favicons (the small images in the browser tabs).

But there is a strategy to design your logo similar to your icon. That means that your icon is also used in your logo. So the icon will be recognized to your logo.
As example Microsoft or also User Experience or Stackoverflow:

---

**Microsoft logo**
[image: Mircosoft logo]
**Microsoft icon**
[image: Microsoft icon]

---

**Stackoverflow logo**
[image: Stackoverflow logo]
**Stackoverflow icon**
[image: Stackoverflow icon]

---

Or just look at the User Experience logo on this site and then on the favicon on this site.

The icon will be assigned faster than when the icon is different to the logo.
But also in this case there are some famous examples, e.g Google or Dribbble:

---

**Google logo**
[image: Google logo]
**Google icon**
[image: Google icon]

---

**Dribbble logo**
[image: Dribbble logo]
**Dribbble icon**
[image: Dribbble icon]

---

A lot of people were already on dribbble and would recognize the logo but not the icon. Same as google. Some (mostly older) smartphone users are confused about the *g* app, because they don't recognize google in it.

I give you the advise, design your logo as you want and try to design a similar icon for your logo.
A last example of a typographic logo / icon design by yahoo:

---

**Yahoo! logo**
[image: Yahoo! logo]
**Yahoo! icon**
[image: Yahoo! icon]

---

Last but not least, an article about the "square icon" for you by [tweakyourbiz](http://tweakyourbiz.com/marketing/2013/06/26/hip-to-be-square-why-a-square-or-circular-icon-is-good-for-your-biz/).

Comment: Really good thoughts and the examples are really helpful! Sadly i'm unable to +1 you.

Comment: @user1720004 but you can "accept" an answer. See also http://ux.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers. And by the way, I think your rep by now is high enough to cast votes.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no such rules. But yes they are inside visible/non visible square area for size proposition like 16X16, 28X28,.....128X128 etc.Which helps in re-sizing or calculation in printing/html,css for better alignment.

For your help: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/inspiration/72-creative-and-smart-typographic-logo-inspiration/

Comment: The examples on the website are amazing. Thank you. Sadly i'm unable to +1 you...

Answer (score 0):

One version of it has to be square to be used in places that demand it, like icons.

A few rules for making a logo that will prevent future problems:

- Should fit in a square, for icons.
- Have a monochromatic version, for places like the notification bar.
- Have a tiny version (down to 16*16 pixels) for use in places like browser tabs.